# why detected object jumps using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, augmented-reality

Ok I have a strange problem. I'll try to describe it as best as I can.

I've learned my app to detect a car when looking on it from the side

```
    Imgproc.cvtColor(aInputFrame, grayscaleImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

    MatOfRect objects = new MatOfRect();

    // Use the classifier to detect cars
    if (cascadeClassifier != null) {
        cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(grayscaleImage, objects, 1.1, 1,
        2, new Size(absoluteObjectSize, absoluteObjectSize),
        new Size());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                Core.rectangle(aInputFrame, dataArray[i].tl(), dataArray[i].br(),
                        new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255), 3);


                mRenderer.setCameraPosition(-5, 5, 60f);
    }
```

Now, this code works nice. I mean that i detects cars and it marks them with green rectangle. The problem is that the marked rectangle jumps like hell. I mean even when the phone is hold still the rectangle jumps from left to right to middle. There is never one still rectangle. I hope I've described the problem properly. I would like to stabilizy the marking cause I want to draw an overlay based on it and I can't make it to jump like this

Answer (score 0):

1. See([1](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale)) the parameters for `detectMultiScale` and it expects
   image of type `CV_8U`. You will need to convert to gray scale image
   with `COLOR_RGBA2GRAY` instead of `COLOR_RGBA2RGB`
2. In `detectMultiScale`, increase the number of neighbours parameter to avoid false positives.
3. Suggestion: If input is a video stream, don't  run
   `detectMultiScale` on every frame. It is slow even if you use `LBP`
   cascades. Try detection in one frame, followed by tracking techniques.